# In Java does using Runtime.getRuntime().exec and p.waiFor() introduce significant overhead for short tasks

Tags: java, runtime.exec

In my Java application I sometimes have to call a non java commandline application to process a file. Often I am processing 20 files, and for each file I use *Runtime.getRuntime().exec* to run the command, attach a process to listen to output and error output and wait for task to finish.

On my PC it work fine, but on a considerably slower NAS device it seems that it is slower running the task via Java then if they were run directly from the command line, each tasks last a few seconds, perhaps a second more than from the command line. Over time this apparent difference is considerable  (note on PC each task only takes about 200 milliseconds).

Does the invoking from Java, creating threads to listen to the output and waiting for completion introduce a significant overhead. Should I rewrite my code to create a single script that will process all files so then I only need one *Runtime.getRuntime().exec* and two strream gobblers.

The difficulty will be reliably parsing the output since I need to account for task sometimes failing, **so my question is whether there is any point, will it make a difference** ?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class StreamGobbler implements Runnable {
    private InputStream     inputStream;
    private StringBuilder   output;

    public StreamGobbler(InputStream inputStream, StringBuilder output) {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
        this.output = output;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        try
        {
            String s = br.readLine();
            if (s != null)
            {
                output.append(s);
            }
            br.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {

        }
    }
}

List<String> params = new ArrayList();
params.add(new File(SongKong.exeFolder, "fpcalc").getAbsolutePath());
params.add(file.getPath());
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(params.toArray(new String[1]));

    StringBuilder output        = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder errorOutput   = new StringBuilder();
    StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new StreamGobbler(p.getInputStream(), output);
    StreamGobbler errorGobbler  = new StreamGobbler(p.getErrorStream(), errorOutput);
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(outputGobbler);
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(errorGobbler);
    p.waitFor();
    fingerprint = output.toString();
```

Comment: I would think that it's `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` itself that is taking a long time, but without access to your particular NAS device it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: Not clear what you are saying

Comment: He is saying that he thinks this is because your NAS is slow.

Comment: Yes I know my NAS is slow but Im not asking why its slower on NAS then PC but if slower if running on NAS from Java then if running directly form NAS cmd line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to know if rewriting the application to exec a script instead of multiple execs will make a difference to execution time.

It probably will do.  However without understanding why the exec'd commands are slow, we can't tell you how much difference it will make ... and whether it is worth the effort.

I suggest that you do some simple experiments in Java:

- compare running some simple command (e.g. `exec("echo hello")`) 20 times versus exec-ing a script that does the same thing:
- do the same involving input files stored on your NAS
- do the same involving executables stored on your NAS (if that is relevant)

These experiments should help you figure out if your proposed way to speed up yout application is likely to work.

It is worth nothing that if your external command is a Java command that has lots of JARs on the classpath, and those JARs are on the NAS, then that *could* significantly affect the startup time.

Comment: Okay seems reasonable approach, since Java 9 has introduced ProcessHandle that should make it easier to interrogate the running process., I will look into that.